# How to combine "day", "month", and "year", "hour" column into a datetime column in Power BI?

Tags: datetime, powerbi

is there any way to combine each  "day", "month", and "year", "hour" column into a datetime column in Power BI? I googled and binged alot, and i even tried many like :

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Create-Date-column-Power-Query-Power-BI/m-p/1699007#M674427

I know there is a DAX that I can just DATE(Year, month, date)
but this is only date, I want Datetime format.

Would anyone please help?

Answer (score 2):

Please try like this

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMjIwMlTSUTIyARKWIIYxkDAG8YyNlWJjAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [year = _t, day = _t, month = _t, hour = _t, minute = _t, second = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"year", Int64.Type}, {"day", Int64.Type}, {"month", Int64.Type}, {"hour", Int64.Type}, {"minute", Int64.Type}, {"second", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each #datetime([year],[month],[day],[hour],[minute],[second])),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", type datetime}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Comment: will try when i a m home